# Not able to change DAG scheduler to execute on 2 days using Python operator

Tags: python, airflow, schedule, airflow-scheduler

I need to change the DAG in order to adjust the scheduler using the Python plugin.
The scheduler must be Wednesday and Friday at 0 0 * * 3,5
I don't know how to schedule on 2 days. I have tried to schedule on friday. Here is the code which I have tried to execute on Friday :-

"""

```
The function validates if the schedule_day parameter is a valid day to execute the task
schedule_day is a number and corresponds to day of the week
1 - Monday
2 - Tuesday
3 - Wednesday
4 - Thursday
5 - Friday
6 - Saturday
7 - Sunday
"""

def _check_valid_day(**kwargs):
    today = datetime.today()
     if today.isoweekday()==kwargs["schedule_day"]:
        return True
     else:
        raise AirflowSkipException("does not correspond to the backup day")
today = datetime.today()
today_str = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#start_date = get_next_weekday(today_str, 4)  # 4 = Friday
start_date = datetime(2022, 4, 2)
dag_id = "${ENV_NAME_UNDER}_data_bq_weekly_backups_dag"

event_collection_project_id = os.environ["EVENT_COLLECTION_PROJECT_ID"]
tables_to_backup = os.environ["TABLES_TO_BACKUP"]
destination_bucket = os.environ["WEEKLY_BQ_BACKUP_BUCKET"]
schedule_day =os.environ["BACKUP_SCHEDULE_DAY"]

default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date for next Friday in order to maintain the scheduler
    # in a consistent state
    "start_date": start_date,
    # To email on failure or retry set 'email' arg to your email and enable
    # emailing here.
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least what's specified in retry_delay
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=10),
    "project_id": event_collection_project_id,
    "schedule_interval": "0 0 * * 5",
}


tables_to_backup_list = get_list_to_backup(tables_to_backup)

with DAG(dag_id=dag_id, default_args=default_dag_args,catchup=False) as dag:

    check_valid_day = PythonOperator(
        task_id='check_valid_day',
        python_callable=_check_valid_day,
        op_kwargs={
                "schedule_day": schedule_day
                },
        )
    task_dict = dict()

    for table_to_backup in tables_to_backup_list:
        dataset = table_to_backup.split(".")[0]
        table = table_to_backup.split(".")[1]
        task_name = f"{dataset}_{table}_table_weekly_backup"
        task_dict[task_name] = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
            task_id=task_name,
            trigger_rule="all_success",
            dag=dag,
            )
        check_valid_day >>  task_dict[task_name]
```

Comment: Was there an error updating the dag schedule from '0 0 * * 5' to '0 0 * * 3,5'?

Comment: But there are changes that also need to be done in Python operator. Don't know how to change those things like creating variable in Airflow and using it here. For example there is also a variable BACKUP_SCHEDULE_DAY=3 which is already used, so I guess need to create 1 more variable but don't know how to use. I am new to Airflow, so don't know how to do for 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried:-"""

```
    SCHEDULE_DAY =  [3,5]
    def _check_valid_day(**kwargs):
        today = datetime.today()
        if today.isoweekday() in "SCHEDULE_DAY":
            return True
        else:
            raise AirflowSkipException("does not correspond to the backup 
    day")


inputFilePattern = f"gs://{geodata_bucket_name}/zips/*.zip"
outputDirectory = f"gs://{geodata_bucket_name}/unzips/"
output_failure_file_path = 
f"gs://{geodata_bucket_name}/unzips/failed.csv"

default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it 
is
    # detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": execution_date,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    # To email on failure or retry set 'email' arg to your email and 
enable
    # emailing here.
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least what's 
specified in retry_delay
    "retries": 1,
    "project_id": project_id,
    # "schedule_interval": GEODATA_SCHEDULE,
    "schedule_interval": "0 0 * * 3,5",
}
```